# How to update the order value by ignoring the isDeleted flag in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having an array of objects like below

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'test1', order: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'qos1', order: 2},
  {id: 3, name: 'qos2', order: 3}
]
```

Instead of deleting the object, I am setting a flag like below

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'test1', order: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'qos1', isDeleted: true, order: 2},
  {id: 3, name: 'qos2', order: 3}
]
```

Now i would like to update the order in the array which is not deleted like below

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'test1', order: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'qos1', isDeleted: true, order: 2},
  {id: 3, name: 'qos2', order: 2}
]
```

I have used forEach and added a condition like below

```
array.forEach((a, i) => {
  if(!a.isDeleted) {
    a.order = i + 1
  }
});
```

But it accounts the index of the object which has isDeleted.But there is one more approach in which i can filter the object which has no isDeleted flag like below

`const updatedArray = array.filter((a) => !a.isDeleted);`

Which returns the object which has no isDeleted flag but i need the isDeleted object as well in the array but the order should consider only for the non-deleted objects.

Comment: snippets two and three are in the same order

Comment: Just do `array.filter((a) => !a.isDeleted).forEach((a, i) => a.order = i + 1)` This will get the non-deleted objects, set the order, then discard the filtered array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a closure over the order and update if necessary.

```js
const data = [{id: 1, name: 'test1', order: 1}, {id: 2, name: 'qos1', isDeleted: true, order: 2}, {id: 3, name: 'qos2', order: 3}];


data.forEach((order => o => {
    if (!o.isDeleted) o.order = order++;
})(1))

console.log(data);
```

Comment: You don't update the order of an `isDeleted` item. If you'll add another `isDeleted` item with `order: 4` you'll see it.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. If there's another item after the deleted, it's order would be 3, but the deleted would stay 4.

Comment: hm: *"but the order should consider only for the non-deleted objects"*

Comment: But the deleted item should have the same index as the one after it.

Comment: I'm wrong. The order of the deleted item doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Create an external `counter`, and only increment it if the item is not deleted:

```js
const arr = [{id: 1, name: 'test1', order: 1}, {id: 2, name: 'qos1', isDeleted: true, order: 2}, {id: 3, name: 'qos2', order: 3}]

let counter = 1

arr.forEach(item => {
  item.order = counter
  
  counter += !item.isDeleted // casting boolean to number false - 0, true - 1
})

console.log(arr)
```